# Configure Alfresco.util.PopupManagers YUI Dialog

Tags: modal-dialog, yui, share, alfresco

I'm trying to configure the **width** for `Alfresco.util.PopupManager.displayPrompt()` but I don't see how to do it.

YUI Dialog has a **width** property, but the only config that I've managed to see, `defaultDisplayPromptConfig` object, doesn't seem to pay much attention to my messing with it.

Specifically, I tried setting `Alfresco.util.PopupManager.defaultDisplayPromptConfig.width` but it didn't work :)

I'm also trying to style up the panel I'm loading (*create-site* style injected panel), but it does not work for now.

Is there a way to configure the PopupManager Prompt object?

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the source for `Alfresco.util.PopupManager.displayPrompt()` contained in [`alfresco.js`](http://sharextras.org/jsdoc/share/community-head/symbols/src/js_alfresco.js.html) then you'll see that the method creates an instance of `YAHOO.widget.SimpleDialog`, which does support a width property.

The problem is that `displayPrompt()` takes only specific configuration options which it passes through to the `SimpleDialog`, so adding an additional `width` parameter to your config will not have any effect, as you can see.

```
// Create the SimpleDialog that will display the text
var prompt = new YAHOO.widget.SimpleDialog("prompt",
      {
         close: c.close,
         constraintoviewport: c.constraintoviewport,
         draggable: c.draggable,
         effect: c.effect,
         modal: c.modal,
         visible: c.visible,
         zIndex: this.zIndex++
      });

// Show the title if it exists
if (c.title)
{
   prompt.setHeader($html(c.title));
}

// Show the prompt text
prompt.setBody(c.noEscape ? c.text : $html(c.text));

// Show the icon if it exists
if (c.icon)
{
   prompt.cfg.setProperty("icon", c.icon);
}

// Add the buttons to the dialog
if (c.buttons)
{
   prompt.cfg.queueProperty("buttons", c.buttons);
}

// Add the dialog to the dom, center it and show it.
prompt.render(parent);
prompt.center();
prompt.show();
```

I like the idea of enhancing the function to support a `width` property and possibly others, but in the meantime you are best off using `SimpleDialog` directly in your own code, modifying the above to add a `width` parameter.

Comment: Well, that's basically a correct answer, although not the desired one :)